# How do I change the default Nagios Threshold values when creating a new host

Tags: nagios

When I create a new host the default threshold values are already set for CPU, memory and disk space on each volume. I am wondering if I can set these default values somewhere in the Nagios config so I don't need to keep changing them when I create a new host?